# ACF(Advance Custom Page) options page changes to be applied across the network as a global option

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Hello I am developing a wordpress multisite and I want create a global options page using ACF options page flexibility and easier maintainability. But the problem is I could not update the options accross the network using the global option.

Is it possible to use ACF options page to create a global options for multisite and update it's options across the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye that is possible - create the options page in your "main site" then when you're wanting to fetch and display the option fields, use the switch_to_blog() function.

Below should demo how to switch out then switch back - I've used it for things like social links and contact details in the past.

```
<?php
// theme options to come from home - root multi site (1)
global $switched; switch_to_blog(1);

// Display your option fields
echo get_field('example_field','options');

// Restore back to current site
restore_current_blog();
?>
```